Minimum Eigenvalue of a Symmetric Matrix
I was solving a problem and got stuck on the following:

Let $\left[p\right] = \left\{1, \ldots, p\right\}$ where $p \in \mathbb{N}$.
Let $\operatorname{P}\left(n, r\right)$ denote the set of all injective functions from $\left[r\right]$ to $\left[n\right]$ and write a typical element as $\sigma = \left[\sigma(1), \ldots,\sigma(r)\right]$ where $1 \leq \sigma(i) \leq n$ and $\sigma(i)'s$ are all distinct.
The Hamming distance between two elements, $\sigma,\tau$ of
$P(n, r)$ can be defined as the number of points in the domain they
disagree on i.e, the cardinality of $\{i \in [r]: \sigma(i)\neq
   \tau(i)\}$.
Order the elements of $P(n, r)$ as
$\{\sigma_1,...\sigma_{^np_k}\}$ and construct a matrix of dimension
$^np_{r}\times ^np_r$ whose $(i,j)^{th}$ entry is $x^{d{(i,j)}}$
where $d(i,j)$ is the Hamming distance between $\sigma_i$ and
$\sigma_j$.
Let $f_{(n,r)}(x)$ be the minimum eigenvalue of the
matrix.
Using Cauchy Interlacing theorem, I managed to prove that $f_{(n,r)}(x)=(1-x)^r$ when $x\in [0,1]$.
Now I am interested in $x\in (-\frac{1}{n-1},0)$. I showed that
$(1-x)^{r-1}(1+(r-1)x)$ is an eigenvalue but unable to check whether
it is the minimum.
I also think that in this interval $f_{(n,r)}(x)>
   f_{(n,r-1)}(x)>(1+(n-1)x)$ for all $n\geq r>1$. I have managed to
prove that all eigenvalues will be integer polynomials in $x$ and
$f_{(n,n)}(x)> f_{(n,n-1)}(x)$.
I need help in proving $f_{(n,r)}(x)>
   f_{(n,r-1)}(x)>(1+(n-1)x)$.

Thanks in Advance !.

Do you know the eigenvectors associated with those eigenvalues?

@Pranay, I am not sure about the eigenvectors. The claim that the eigenvalues are polynomials can be proved by noticing that matrix sits inside a Bose-Mesner Algbera generated by the distance based Association Scheme.
